# ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED for URL in Android webview

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, jetpack

Can anyone help me with this issue which I'm getting on the webview. I'm using proxy to use url.

with error code: -11, description: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED for URl while loading the url on the webview.

```
private fun setProxy(proxyUrl: String) {
 if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.PROXY_OVERRIDE)) {
     
     val proxyConfig: ProxyConfig = ProxyConfig.Builder()

         .addProxyRule(proxyUrl)

         .addDirect() // When the proxy is not working, use direct connect, maybe?

         .build()

     ProxyController.getInstance().setProxyOverride(

         proxyConfig,

         {

             /* Success callback */

         },

         {

             /* Error*/

             Timber.d("setProxy:---> Some error occurred!")

         },

     )

 } else {

     Timber.d("setProxy's else part")

 }
```